# Change model data on the fly in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, filter, dom-manipulation

I need to show a JSON array inside a textarea, but with some minor modification.

The JSON array located inside 'list' and `$scope.list` is bound to a JSON object.

How can I change delimiters on the fly from commas to `\n` in agnularjs?

http://jsfiddle.net/Pn5Xv/

List json:

```
{
    "items" : [ { "outputs" : ["one","two"] } ]
}
```

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="record in list">
  <textarea ng-model="record.outputs"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: is it showing up in textarea?? Can u post a jsfiddle??

Comment: added, http://jsfiddle.net/Pn5Xv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [custom filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) for this task:

JavaScript:

```
myApp.filter('arrayToString', function() {
    return function(inputArray) {
        return inputArray.join("\n");
    };
});
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="record in list">
    <textarea>{{record.outputs | arrayToString}}</textarea>
</div>
```

**Notes:**

- This you do not use `ng-model` anymore you need track changes by yourself and reverse the whole input, `ng-change` or `ng-form` should be helpful.
- Make sure you filter is a dependency of you app.

Comment: ng-form and ng-change required ng-model and doesn't work without it. Is it possible use <textarea>{{record.outputs | arrayToString}}</textarea> with model ?

Comment: Thanks, I have already found solution: <textarea ng-init="txt = (record.outputs | arrayToString)" ng-model="txt"></textarea>